# Monotonicity of r-mean convergence

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose that $X_n → x$ in s-mean as $n → \infty$ and that $0<r<s$.

1) Prove that $X_n → x$ in r-mean as $n →\infty$.

2) Hence show that $E(x_n)→ E(x)$ as $n →\infty$ if $s\geq 1$.

I proved part 1, and proved part 2 when s=1. What about $s>1$?

Comment: Use Dominated convergence Theorem [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) and [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder%27s_inequality).

Comment: I show if s=2 the var(x_n) \to var(x)  explian what you mean please

Comment: use $E(X_n) \leqslant E((X_n)^{2})^{1/2}$ and same for $E(X)$ also. Then use DCT.

Comment: assume $x_n$ $ \to$ x in 2-mean implies E($x_n$) $\to$ E(x) as n $\to$ $\infty$  ... my attempt $E|x_n -x|^2=E|(x_n-x)(x_n-x)|$ $\leq$ $(E|x_n-x|^2)^1\2 (E(|x_n +x|)^2)^1\2$ @TRUSKI

Answer (score 0):

but now we must prove 2) if s>1 .... I attempt to solve it

E$|x_n -x|$$\leq $E($|x_n-x|$  |$x_n +x|)$ $\leq$ $E(|x_n-x|^s)^(1/s) (E(|x_n-x|r)^1\r)$ but E$(|x_n-x|^s)^(1\s)$ $\to$ 0 as n $\to$ $\infty$